# Spring Boot security is not working in the simplest case

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a very simple spring boot application to test out some security features. But I failed at the first step and I don't really understand why.

My application is a WebFlux application and has 2 users and 2 endpoints. One of the endpoint can be reached with user having "ADMIN" role, but for the other the user should only be authenticated. But I alway get HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) response.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo-security</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo-security</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot Security</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

</project>
```

These are my endpoints:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    Mono<ServerResponse> message(ServerRequest request) {
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just("Hello World!"), String.class);
    }

    Mono<ServerResponse> somethingElse(ServerRequest request) {
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just("Hello Else!"), String.class);
    }

    @Bean
    RouterFunction<?> routes() {
        return RouterFunctions.route().GET("/message", this::message)
            .GET("/else", this::somethingElse)
            .build();
    }
}
```

And finally the security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user1 = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("notAdmin")
            .password("notAdmin")
            .roles("SYSTEM", "USER")
            .build();
        UserDetails user2 = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
            .build();

        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user1,user2);      
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/message")
                .hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .build();
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the service and what I get in response (pls note, the response is the same for both endpoints):

```
$ curl -v -uadmin:admin http://localhost:8080/else
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> GET /else HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< content-length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Just right after I clicked the submit button I found out what is the problem. An **.httpBasic()** is missing. Here is the correct security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user1 = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("notAdmin")
            .password("notAdmin")
            .roles("SYSTEM", "USER")
            .build();
        UserDetails user2 = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
           .build();

        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user1,user2);
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/message")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .build();
    }
}
```

Sorry, if I caused any inconvenience!

Comment: I'm glad you returned to the question to share the solution!